# correlated query in join of MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Why is there an error => `uknown column devgeo.id` in a part of the whole query? Below.

```
' select devgeo.id from device_geolocation devgeo inner join (select concat(''received_posts_'', cast(devgeo.id as char))) rcv_posts on(devgeo.id=rcv_posts.id)',
```

Also, why setting `@a=devgeo.id` and using `@a` in `cast(@a as char)` yields an error that there is no column in `where`? Below.

```
rcv_posts.post_id != ', cast(post_id as char),
```

First, I count that each subquery has an access to its parent query aliases.
Second, as I experienced when implementing the first part of the whole query in `where` clause using `exists` operator, but there was the same error - `unknown column devgeo.id`. After using an user variable there was an error - `unknown column` - but for the concatenated table name in the `exists` operator.

@for Gordon

```
set @q = (select concat('insert into ', created_table_name, 
                            ' select @a=devgeo.id from device_geolocation devgeo inner join (select concat(''received_posts_'', cast(@a as char))) rcv_posts on(devgeo.id=rcv_posts.id)',
                            ' where devgeo.id != ', cast(deviceid as char),  
                            ' and devgeo.id != ', cast(post_device_id as char), 
                            ' and rcv_posts.post_id != ', cast(post_id as char),                                    
                            ' limit ', cast(x as char)));
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  You should put a better representation of your actual query in the question.  For instance, the `join` columns are not defined.  The one column in the subquery is not given an alias.  There is no `from` clause, but presumably one is there.

Comment: What do you mean saying join columns are not defined? There is from clause in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This is the important part of your query:

```
select @a=devgeo.id
from device_geolocation devgeo inner join
      (select concat(''received_posts_'', cast(@a as char))
      ) rcv_posts
      on(devgeo.id=rcv_posts.id)',
                        '
```

It makes no sense.  The column `rcv_posts.id` is not defined, so the `on` clause will fail, regardless of what is in the subquery.  Perhaps your intention is:

```
select @a = devgeo.id
from device_geolocation devgeo cross join
      (select concat(''received_posts_'', cast(@a as char)) as var
      )
```

Or, perhaps you intend to have a `from` clause in the subquery.

Comment: I need to refer to the table formed by the subquery. There should be no id in the received_posts_X post_id column.

Comment: And yet you refer to `rcv_posts.id` in the `on` clause.

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'rcv_posts.post_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: How would you achieve this filtering using one query?